# Reset model poses in a python script

Tags: ros, gazebo, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I wrote a script with a for loop, where inside I navigate a robot and save the camera output/trajectories.

At the end of the loop I would like to reset the poses of the model, but unfortunately trying

```
self.reset = rospy.Publisher("gazebo/reset_models", Empty, queue_size=10) 
self.reset.publish(Empty())
```

does not work.
Do you have an idea on what might work there? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266940/reset-model-poses-in-a-python-script/) by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Isn't `/gazebo/reset_models` a *service*, not a topic?

---

> I am sorry, could you please help me by telling what should I type into my for loop in order to get the model poses reset?

I don't know about "get model poses reset", but for invoking the `/gazebo/reset_simulation` service, the following should work:

```
import rospy
from std_srvs.srv import Empty

# maybe do some 'wait for service' here
reset_simulation = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/reset_simulation', Empty)

# invoke
reset_simulation()
```

See also the [Writing a Simple Service and Client (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) tutorial, specifically the *Writing the Client Node* section.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on 2017-07-21**:
You are right, thanks for pointing this out :)

Unfortunately, I still didn't manage to reset the world inside my script. I tried to do the following:
`self.reset = rospy.Service('gazebo/reset_simulation', Empty); self.reset(Empty)`

However, `rosservice call /gazebo/reset_world "{}"` works fine.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-21**:
I think you'll need to add the `/` prefix, otherwise you're specifying a relative name.

**Comment by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on 2017-07-21**:
Thanks, but unfortunately, it does not work. I have tried self.reset = rospy.Service('reset', "/gazebo/reset_simulation", Empty), but I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_request_class'

**Comment by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on 2017-07-21**:
I can find /gazebo/reset_simulation in the rosservice list, but when I go to the folder gazebo_msgs.srv, there is no reset_simulation.srv :( any idea on what can I do to import this service?

**Comment by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on 2017-07-21**:
Moreover, I could not find any file "reset_simulation" on my computer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-21**:
I'm not sure what you are trying to do. `rospy.Service('reset', "/gazebo/reset_simulation", Empty)` that is not how you should initialise any service object, neither server nor client.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-21**:\

> I could not find any file "reset_simulation" on my computer.

Where are you expecting to find it? The service is of type `Empty` apparently, so you'd have to look for `Empty.srv`, which is in [std_srvs](http://wiki.ros.org/std_srvs).

**Comment by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on 2017-07-21**:
I am sorry, could you please help me by telling what should I type into my for loop in order to get the model poses reset?

**Comment by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on 2017-07-21**:
I am wondering, what is the good way to initialize rospy service. self.reset = rospy.Service('gazebo/reset_simulation', Empty) comes to my mind, but I am missing one argument. Unfortunately, I do not know what should it be.

**Comment by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on 2017-07-21**:
the second argument gives me AttributeError: type object 'Empty' has no attribute '_request_class'

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-21**:
What I showed in my answer was only an example.

If I do exactly what I wrote there, I can successfully reset my Gazebo here, so please check what you have done on your side.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-21**:
And please take note of the `/` prefix on the `gazebo/reset_simulation` name! It is important.

**Comment by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on 2017-07-21**:
Thank you so much for your time!! I found out that i have declared Empty as a msg and service at the same time, which caused my program to fail :)

I really appreciate your help! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I've created this very short [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSvM7dEilhk) that shows exactly how to do this. Maybe by watching how to do it step by step it's easier to understand. Hope it helps!

EDIT: In the Video, I just show an example of how to implement a solution to the question. It might be helpful for someone to visualize step by step how it can be done. Code used:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_srvs.srv import Empty

rospy.init_node('reset_world')

rospy.wait_for_service('/gazebo/reset_world')
reset_world = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/reset_world', Empty)

reset_world()
```

---

Originally posted by [Alberto E.](https://answers.ros.org/users/31003/alberto-e./) with karma: 356 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on 2017-07-24**:
Although I have already done that, I think it might help other people with the same problem. Thanks for your contribution, Alberto! :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-24**:
Whenever referring to a video, please include a short description of what it shows. In case the video ever disappears, your answer basically becomes useless.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-24**:\

> Well, basically I've implemented a solution to the question

so that is basically what I already had in my answer, right?

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2022-10-07**:
Works for me in Noetic.